# ¿Cómo colocar la fecha del sistema en un label de JFrame?

Tags: java, jframe, label

Quiero que la fecha actual del sistema aparezca en un label de un JFrame, el problema es que al momento de ejecutarlo, no aparece nada. ¿Cómo puedo solucionar esto?
Aqui el código:

```
 private void txtDateActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
        Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
        String day = Integer.toString(calendar.get(Calendar.DATE));
        String month = Integer.toString(calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH));
        String year = Integer.toString(calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR));
        String date = day+"/"+month+"/"+year;
        txtDate.setText(date);


txtDate = new javax.swing.JTextField();
txtTime = new javax.swing.JTextField();
```

Time:

```
txtTime.setEditable(false);
        txtTime.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(31, 37, 51));
        txtTime.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Dubai", 1, 14)); // NOI18N
        txtTime.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(153, 153, 0));
        txtTime.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.JTextField.CENTER);
        txtTime.setBorder(null);
        txtTime.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                txtTimeActionPerformed(evt);
```

Date:

```
txtDate.setEditable(false);
        txtDate.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(31, 37, 51));
        txtDate.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Dubai", 1, 14)); // NOI18N
        txtDate.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(153, 153, 0));
        txtDate.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.JTextField.CENTER);
        txtDate.setBorder(null);
        txtDate.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                txtDateActionPerformed(evt);
```

Comment: Hola Marce, coloque un MessageDialog y me aparecio correctamente la fecha, pero al momento de ver en el textField no aparece nada. La verdad no entiendo la razón, sabiendo que todo está bien.

Comment: eso es todo el código acerca de txtDate. Yo creo el textField en design y automáticamente me aparece en source, donde ya le agrego el código a emplear en ese textField. También me pasa con otro textField que es para mostrar la hora, igualmente intente con otro textField de ensayo y tampoco muestra el mensaje

Comment: Si lo ingreso manualmente, si me aparece el texto al momento de ejecutar el programa.

Comment: Listo, ahi coloqué todo lo relacionado tanto de txtDate como de txtTime que existe en el source. Siguiendo tu pregunta, no no me arroja ningún error.

Comment: Creo que ahi está el por qué no funciona. ¿Sabes como puedo activar la función?

Comment: Mi intención es que el usuario al entrar en el programa, aparezca el dia y la hora arriba en la pantalla(como un celular). ¿Se puede hacer eso sin necesidad de un boton adicional?

Comment: agrega un método por ejemplo **public void iniciar()** y le pones el código que generaste antes, luego en algún lugar de tu clase "main" o como se llame, creas la clase que contiene tu interfaz gráfica, algo así, **Gui gui = new GUI();**, en la linea siguiente pones **gui.iniciar();** y, después de haber creado la interfaz, ejecutará el metodo que le pone el texto al JTextField.

Comment: Ya me funcionó. Muchas gracias por tu ayuda y paciencia Marce!

Comment: Un placer Idolo!!!

Answer (score 0):

En realidad hay muchas formas de resolverlo y con menos código.

Lo más sencillo y que recomendaría es con `SimpleDateFormat`:

```
private void txtDateActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
    String date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").format(new Date());
    txtDate.setText(date);
}
```